# Change array output to one without brackets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, transform

I changed a sparse dictionary into an array with (np.asarray). Then, I wrote a function that used that array to return the answer of a formula. However, I did that in a way the output includes the double brackets. Let's say the output is now:

```
[[7.58939191]]
```

but should be:

```
7.58939191
```

Can someone say how I can change this easily? Or do I have to share my function for this?

Comment: Remove the brackets before outputting, of course. Or just output the value inside the array.

Comment: Removing the brackets before outputting is causing a 'DeprecationWarning'.

Comment: The brackets in the display string mean that the item is either a numpy array (2d) or a list (of lists).  They aren't just decoration.  They are a clue as to nature of the object.  Once you understand the nature of the object, you should be able to extract a scalar if needed (e.g. with indexing or `.item()` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be `item` method:

```
x.item(0)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html):

> Copy an element of an array to a standard Python scalar and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a numpy array, then compress the dimension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.squeeze(np.asarray(a))
```

Then you can use a just like a number, for example:

```
b = a + 1
```

Comment: But this `a` is still an array, albeit a 0d one.